# Do I have to use .each() for this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to look up all the items with a certain selector and return all of their titles as quickly as possible.  I know I can use `.each()` to loop through them and populate a variable, but I would like to use `.join()` if possible.

Here is how I would do it using `.each()`

```
 var pop = "";
 $("a").each(function(i,v){
    var pop = pop + $(this).attr("title") + ',';
 });

 //now pop looks like: "title1,title2,etc"
```

How could I return all the titles in a CSV format using `.join()` ?

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
var pop = $("a").title.join(',');
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to iterate the array, yes. But you can use [map](http://api.jquery.com/map/) for this specific case:

```
var arr = $("a").map(function () { return $(this).attr('title') }).get();
var csv = arr.join(',');
```

Comment: You'll need a `.get()` after the map for this to work: http://api.jquery.com/map/

Comment: just curious, is there a performance difference between this and .each()? questions specifies as quickly as possible

Comment: @aw04 map seems slightly faster, at least in Firefox: http://jsperf.com/each-vs-map123123

Comment: @jgillich I was creating the test too :)

Comment: For some reason I get this error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` on the `.join()` line, even when the `arr` object has 2 values in it in the console.